# Angularjs - $stateChangeStart working only two times when the browser back button pressed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a code something like this

```
$scope.on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

It stop state change when user clicks browser back button twice but third time it wont fire this `$stateChangeStart` listener instead of this it navigate to the previous page or window.onbeforeunload method will be fired.

Why `$stateChangeStart` listener is not fired in the third time when i press browser back button?

Comment: use [$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded')], maybe helps you

Comment: Thanks Maher. I am going to use $locationChangeStart for browser back buttons. Actually I want to show error message popup when there is some unsaved changes in the page while user clicks browser back button.